# Find the Xor value between two integers who value is 2

Tags: algorithm, math, data-structures

Given an array consisting of N integers. Is it possible to find the number 
of (a[i],a[j]) pairs such that 1 <= i < j< = N and the bitwise Xor value is exactly 2 with a time complexity less than O(n^2) or is there any mathematical formula to find the number of pairs like a[i] ^ a[j] == 2.

Constraints

1≤N≤10^5

1≤Ai≤10^6

Comment: @alvits Please, avoid sarcasms and better teach the OP how to make a good question.

Comment: @Ripi2 - where is the sarcasm in an honest comment? The question was edited after I have posted my comment. The answer below is inline with my comment.

Comment: @alvits "Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements." (and this comment ["Add(s) relevant but minor or transient information to a post"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An efficient solution of this problem can be of `O(n)` time complexity. The idea is based on the fact that `arr[i] ^ arr[j]` is equal to `2` if and only if `arr[i] ^ 2` is equal to `arr[j]`.

```
1) Initialize result as 0.
2) Create an empty hash set "s".
3) Do following for each element arr[i] in arr[]
   (a)    If 2 ^ arr[i] is in "s", then increment result by 1.
   (b)    Insert arr[i] into the hash set "s".
3) return result.
```

Here is C++ implementation:

```
int xorPairCount(vector<int>& arr) {
    int n= (int)arr.size();
    int result = 0;

    unordered_set<int> s;

    for (int i = 0; i < n ; i++) {
        // If there exist an element in set s
        // with XOR equals to 2^arr[i], that means
        // there exist an element such that the
        // XOR of element with arr[i] is equal to
        // 2, then increment count.
        if (s.find(2^arr[i]) != s.end())
            result++;

        // Make element visited
        s.insert(arr[i]);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Note that, for this solution, I assumed there is no duplicate in the array. If duplicate allowed, then the solution will be a bit different. Let me know.

### Update

If there are duplicates in the array, use an hashmap instead of hashset to count the frequency of each number, because for each occurrence, there will be one count. Here is the update of the above code:

```
int xorPairCount(vector<int>& arr) {
    int n= (int)arr.size();
    int result = 0;

    unordered_map<int, int> m;

    for (int i = 0; i < n ; i++) {
        int curr_xor =  2^arr[i];
        if (m.find(curr_xor) != m.end())
            result += m[curr_xor];

        m[arr[i]]++;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for providing the solution.